# How to add toggle (show/hide) in a comment system -JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out a way to add toggle in a comment system. It should hide/show the content when clicking on plus/minus sign. I've tried to adjust some of the solutions I've found online but none worked for me.
I currently have a function for adding comments and displaying them in an ordered list, but the toggle function doesn't work for me.
What can I do to make it work?

```
<script>
    var ans = [];
        function postcomments() {
            var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
            var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;
            var lastpos = ans.length;
            var current = new Date();
            console.log(current);
            var time=current.getHours()+":"+(current.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + current.getMinutes();
            var date=current.getDate()+"."+(current.getMonth()+1)+"."+current.getFullYear();
            ans[lastpos] = '<img src="Media/minusicon.png" onclick="toggle(document.getElementById("txt");)" style="width:8%;" class="plusminusicon">'  + " "+" Sent by"+" " +'<a href="#.html">'+ fname +'</a>'+ " "+ " on" +" " +date+ " "+ "at" +" "+time +'<br>' +'<span class="txt">'+ msg +'</span>'+'<br>'+'-------------------------------';
            var ol = document.getElementById("showcomments");
            ol.innerHTML = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
                ol.innerHTML += "<li id="+(i+1)+">" + ans[i] + "</li>";
            }
        }

          function toggle(x) {
          if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
          } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
          }
        } 
      
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first of all you are referring to "txt" via **getElementById when it is a Class.**
You should make it an ID and add some **unique identifier** to it, like lastpos for example
An ID always has to be unique for your code to work. Hard to tell without the HTML it puts out but this might also apply to fname and msg.

Second of all you have call the getElementById("txt") in quotes inside the onclick quotes. You have to replace them by **&quot;** otherwise the browser thinks it's the end of the onclick statement.
Also get rid of the semicolon at the end if you use it as a parameter.

So it should look something like this:

```
ans[lastpos] = '<img src="Media/minusicon.png" onclick="toggle(document.getElementById(&quot;txt&quot;))" style="width:8%;" class="plusminusicon">'  + " "+" Sent by"+" " +'<a href="#.html">'+ fname +'</a>'+ " "+ " on" +" " +date+ " "+ "at" +" "+time +'<br>' +'<span id="txt'+lastpos+'">'+ msg +'</span>'+'<br>'+'-------------------------------';
```

There are more elegant ways to solve this but I think with the mentioned modifications your code should work

Answer (score 1):

## FIRST OF ALL...


I noticed that you have both "txt" class and id from your code. This is kinda wrong and strange. **ID must be unic for ONLY ONE HTML element**.

*after that...*

## Try changing this line:

```
<script>
ans[lastpos] = '<img src="Media/minusicon.png" onclick="toggle(document.getElementById("txt");)" style="width:8%;" class="plusminusicon">'  + " "+" Sent by"+" " +'<a href="#.html">'+ fname +'</a>'+ " "+ " on" +" " +date+ " "+ "at" +" "+time +'<br>'
    +'<span class="txt">'+ msg +'</span>'+'<br>'+'-------------------------------';
</script>
```

---

### TO THIS:

*obviously you have to solve the problem of ID and class names first.*

I think you can change the

```
`
```

character with

```
"
```

without problems

```
<script>
ans[lastpos] = `<img src='Media/minusicon.png' onclick='toggle(document.getElementById('txt'))' style='width:8%;' class='plusminusicon'> Sent by <a href='#.html'>${fname}</a> on ${date} at ${time}<br><span class='txt'>${msg}</span><br>-------------------------------`;
</script>
```

---

NOTE: `${fname}` this pattern is useful to prevent your string from being filled with + signs for concatenating variables. However, this is not necessary.